# PHP Checkin/Checkout Time Calculations

Tags: php, time, date-arithmetic

I've got an array of data in php - it isn't perfect however this is an example of one of them.

```
"time_in": [
    "22:17:23",
    "22:17:26",
    "22:17:27",
    "22:17:28",
    "22:18:54",
    "22:19:28",
    "22:20:49",
    "22:20:52",
    "22:22:17",
    "22:31:13"
],
"time_out": [
    "22:17:33",
    "22:18:47",
    "22:18:52",
    "22:18:52",
    "22:19:12",
    "22:22:08"
]
```

I need to figure out a formula to calculate the `$total_time_in` and `$total_time_out`

I'm aware that if there is a "checked in" entry and no "checked out" entry for the final item, then it could potentially say they've been checked in for a long time - but thats okay for the time being - Unless of course the answer can address that issue by capping it at midnight.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what those 2 arrays represent

Comment: one array contains times that a user has checked in, the other array contains times the user checked out. The idea is to find out how long the user has been both checked in and out

Comment: so do you want the difference between element 1 of time in and element 1 of time out, or do you want the differences between element 1 and 2 of time in, and such?

Comment: There's not a "formula".  How would you figure it out if you were doing it with paper and pencil?

Comment: @phpmeh I don't know what it will be - it might turn out it is the difference, it might turn out its not - as plainly english as I can put it i need to find out how long the users have been checked in

Comment: @AndyLester I have no idea how you'd do it - thats why I'm asking how I would go about solving this

Comment: @OwenMelbourne "I have no idea how you'd do it" --- so do you have an algorithm from your supervisor or not? If now, why do you think that we know what they want from you?

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 5.3 you can use DateTime object, they provide an easy way to deal with date and time. So to begin with you can use the static method createFromFormat bellow, knowing that the resulting object will be initialized at the current date.

```
$a =  DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '22:17:23');
$b =  DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '22:17:33');
$interval = $a->diff($b); 
echo $interval->format('%R%s second(s)'); 
echo "\n"
```

Next if you have a variable $in = ['t1', t2 ..] and $out you merely can doing like that :

```
$k = 0;
array_map(function($inputTime) use ($out, &$k) {
$a =  DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $inputTime);
if (!isset($out[$k])) {
  return;
}
$b =  DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $out[$k] );
$interval = $a->diff($b); 
echo $interval->format('%R%s second(s)'); 
echo "\n";
$k++;
},$in);
```

Hope this can help ;)

Comment: How would this work with multiple "out" values? considering its not associative in any way shape or form? thanks

Comment: you've to iterate over the $out array, that's what the array_map function is doing, but you can use a for, foreach or while loop, in all case you have to iterate over something... then you can store the result in an array (must be pass by reference with array_map like $k) or a specific object.